# Calculating Percent of Total in a Hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax

Using the Contoso database, I have a report that looks as follows:

[image]

The measure for Percent of Total is:

```
Percent of Total = 
    VAR SelectedSalesTotal = CALCULATE(
        [Sales Amount],
        ALLSELECTED(Products[Brand Name]),
        ALLSELECTED(Customers[Country])
    )

    RETURN
    DIVIDE([Sales Amount], SelectedSalesTotal)
```

Now I want to change this so that the percentage for each country is not the percentage based on total sales, but based on brand name sales. So, for example, for the brand A. Datum and Canada, instead of 4.48%, it should be 26.96% (7,011,941.77 / 26,007,534.55). The Percent of Total values for each brand shouldn't change. So, A. Datum should remain at 16.62%.

I have been unable to figure out how to do this.

The data model looks like this:

[image]